# SSD initialization issue on Windows 10, 7 and Mac OS but shows on BIOS - is this broken?

Tags: partitioning, ssd

I have SK hynix CANVAS 512 GB |ONFI DDR NAND Flash Adopted | SATA3 6.0 Gbpsat hand.

It failed to be recognized or partitioned using Mac OS Disk Utility and Windows 10. Result of my google search has led me to believe that Windows 7 installation to use the feature as the only solution.

So I installed and it is recognized on BIOS, tried:

1. using Computer management based on this [link](http://forums.crucial.com/t5/Crucial-SSDs/How-to-initialize-your-SSD-Windows/ta-p/111492)
   -> but no pop up, no recognition
2. using CMD following [these steps](https://www.disk-partition.com/diskpart/initialize-disk-4125.html)
   -> STUCK on `convert gpt`

Can someone kindly save me.. I just want to make sure this SSD is workable or not, then I can decide whether to throw it or give it to someone. Maybe it is safe to determine this SSD is rotten? Wow I spent so much time installing windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried Linux? You can boot a Live-CD onto your PC and use `gparted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather comment then answer but i dont have enough reputation ATM.

What I would do is to have a look at the device under Computer Management device driver. It is possible that the driver is having a problem installing. If you see a new entry when you add the drive then try right click and uninstall then reboot..

The other thing to be weary of is the cable. I have one cable just plain does not work try swap it for another if possible.

lastly. get seagate's disk utility from the [website](https://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/discwizard/). This has helped me with any drives I have had problems with.

Comment: It was safe to say this ssd was broken from the start. appreciate your suggestions still. wud like to help you collect reps